# My rotated TextView is cut off. What i have to do?

Tags: android, rotation, textview

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--left-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/nero"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Nothing important"
                android:textSize="40dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>



            <!--right yellow column-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_barra_nord"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="@color/giallo"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:textColor="@color/nero"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="try"
                    />
                    <!--android:text="long text"-->


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i'd like to have this effect for every text:

[image: the effect that always I want]

but if I try to add a longer text, my text will be cut off:

[image: cut effect]

I see that lot of people have this problem, but I haven't found anything helpful.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: I think we need to look at complete layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont think that the rest of my layout is significant. Anyways i add all my layout.

Comment: you should try calculating the height depending upon your text and assigning it to text view.

Comment: i solved the problem adding a fixed value to the ` android:layout_width` of the TextView. Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TextView width` is `match_parent` which means your `TextView` will have the same `width` as your parent `LinearLayout`. Your `LinearLayout` have a narrow width so your `TextView` will have a narrow width too.

**EDIT:** You have to think of your `TextView` as if he is on the *same orientation as your parent*. If he had the same orientation you would have the TextView with a narrow width.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I know that my TextView have a narrow width. But i dont know how to enlarge it. I have tried to edit from java code but nothing changed.

Comment: The problem is the match_parent on the width. Try to give a fixed value like 100dp and see what happens. Try to put a `minWidth` on your TextView.

Comment: wow i add fixed value to the TextView (300dp) and `android:gravity="center"` to the LinearLayout of the "right yellow column" and to the TextView. Now it work perfectly. Answer was more easier than my expectations :) Very very thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following attribute of TextView

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

so that it stretch down to the full parent height.

Comment: already tried. The text now is centered but still cut. (Grazie per la risposta!)